# Human attribute classifier

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to incorporate human attributes(e.g. gender, age, hair color) for image retrieval project.

For that I need to learn these human attributes from my training facial images. So I was wandering if there is any library available in matlab or python to learn these human attributes from facial images. This library should give me some measure or score of human attributes corresponding to that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PyFaces](https://code.google.com/p/pyfaces/) implements face recognition using eigenfaces.  It depends on [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) for image handling and [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) for the matrix calculations.  See [this blogpost](http://pyfaces.blogspot.com/) for an explanation of how it works.